# Exception list of the project for organisation level hooks in Github Enterprise

Tags: github, hook, webhooks, github-enterprise

I have a hook configured in **Github** in *Organization* level which applies all the projects underneath of that organization by default. But I want to **eliminate** this hook **for specific projects** of this organization. Is it possible to set up somehow in **Github Enterprise**?

Answer (score 0):

No, this isn't possible.  You will either need to configure the individual repos to have the hooks you need, or have the org-level hook be smart enough to ignore the things it does not need.

Perhaps you can write a simple webhook forwarder that has the logic you need?